# Функция для выборки из базы по ID

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе есть 50 записей.
Мне нужно вывести название каждой записи на странице, в разных местах страницы, поэтому *while* решил не использовать.

Сначала думал делать так:

```
$linke_from_home_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name, link FROM `link_to_home` WHERE `id` = '1' LIMIT 1")); //запись 1
echo $linke_from_home_1['name']; //вывод имени
```

Но понял что 50 таких выборок из базы на странице не лучший вариант.
Тогда попытался создать функцию для этого, чтоб было так:

```
echo vibor_zap(1, 2); //где 1 - id записи, 2 - поля с именем.
```

И соответственно чтоб на странице выводилось имя этой записи.

Вот мой код этой функции:

```
function vibor_zap($ID) {
    $linke_from_home = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name, link FROM `link_to_home` WHERE `id` = '".$ID."' LIMIT 1"));
}

echo vibor_zap(1, 2);
```

Но ничего не выводит.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас функция ничего не возвращает. Вы патаетесь с помощью echo вывести по сути void (ничего).

Нужно либо вернуть из функции значение и его подставить в echo:

```
function vibor_zap($ID) {
    //...
    return $linke_from_home;
}
$res = vibor_zap(1,2);
echo $res;
```

Либо сделать вывод в самой функциии:

```
function vibor_zap($ID) {
    //...
    echo $linke_from_home;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что не правильно, это ориентация на расширение mysql, оно давно признано устаревшим и искллючается из PHP 7. Однако, даже в рамках этого расширения вы работате не совсем корректно, так как функция mysql_query() возвращает результирующую таблицу, по которой вы как раз должны пройтись циклом. Выполнять 50 раз запрос - это плохо, это возрастание нагрузки на базу данных и сеть в 50 раз (ну может чуть-чуть поменьше).

```
$query = "SELECT name, link FROM `link_to_home` WHERE `id` = '1' LIMIT 1"
$lnk = mysql_query($query);
if(!$lnk) exit("Ошибка выполнения запроса: ".mysql_error());
// Функция mysql_fetch_assoc() принимает дескриптор $lnk и 
// каждый вызов возвращает новую запись из результирующей таблицы,
// до тех пор, пока в ней не исчерпаются данные
while($linke_from_home_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($lnk)) {
  echo $linke_from_home_1['name']."<br />";
}
```

Рассмотрите возможность работы через расширение PDO, это более современный подход

```
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

  $query = "SELECT name, link FROM `link_to_home` WHERE `id` = '1' LIMIT 1";
  $lnk = $pdo->query($query);

  while($link = $lnk->fetch()) {
    echo $link['name']."<br />";
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Вы написали кое *while* , а мне он не подходит, так как мне нужно записи выводит в разных местах. Поэтому именно подобной функцией было бы не плохо

Comment: Поместите результат в массив и выводите данные из него в разных местах, не обязательно выводить их тут же.